# why my laravel is not sending form data in email

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

i am trying to send this data to email

**dynamic_email_template.blade.php**

```
<p>Hi, This is {{ $data['name'] }}</p>
<p>I have some query like {{ $data['message'] }}.</p>
<p>It would be appriciative, if you gone through this feedback.</p>
```

but problem is that `$data['name']` & `$data['message']` is missing in received email

in model and controller even i am receiving this data i have checked it using `dd($this->data)`
here is my route

```
Route::get('/sendemail', 'SendEmailController@index');

Route::post('/sendemail/send', 'SendEmailController@send')->name('send.mail');
```

**my controller**

```
public function send(Request $request)
{
    $data = array(
        'name'      =>  $request->name,
        'message'   =>   $request->message
    );
    
   // dd($data);

 Mail::to('hamzaqureshi401@gmail.com')->send(new SendMail($data));
 return back()->with('success', 'Thanks for contacting us!');

}
```

**my model**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SendMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        dd($this->data);
        return $this->from('scoops@creamery.pk')->subject('New Customer Equiry')->view('dynamic_email_template')->with('data', $this->data);
    }
}

?>
```

where i am doing mistake any help will be thankfull

Comment: `$this->data` is already an array, don't pass it in inside of another array in your with statement

Comment: sorry it was written mistakenly i knew that and i removed but i still have no input data

Comment: Try to delete dd (dump and die) in build method.

Comment: it is just for testing i have deleted it i was checking is data is rendring or not from form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want you can try
in dynamic_blade

```
<p>Hi, This is {{ $name }}</p>
<p>I have some query like {{ $email }}.</p>
<p>It would be appriciative, if you gone through this feedback {{ $message1 }}.</p>
```

and only use controller except using model class

```
        $data =  array(
        'name' =>     $request->name,
         'email' =>    $request->email,
          'message1' =>  $request->message

    );

   Mail::send('dynamic_email_template',$data, function ($message) {

    $message->from('example@mail.com', 'Contact');

    $message->to('example@mail.com')->subject('Contact');

});        
      
          return back()->with('success', 'Thanks for contacting us!');
```